# Python + sdl2: list or bytearray to c_void_p

Tags: python, sdl-2

I'm currently writing a Gameboy Emulator in Python. I want to use pysdl2 for the graphic output.

I have a list of RGB-Values (3 Values per Pixel, so the list is 256x256x3). This is the background, not what the actual screen will show.

Direct pixel manipulation is too slow, so I thought about using `sdl2.SDL_UpdateTexture` to update the whole Texture at once. But I'm not able to convert my list to the necessary `c_void_p`-type. 
Is there an easy way to do this? Or is there a better way to achieve enough FPS? I didn't think it would be this difficult to update an image 60 times per second.

A short example:

```py
import sdl2


pic = [0xff] * 256*256*3

window = sdl2.SDL_CreateWindow(b"Gameboy Emulator", 256, 256, 256, 256, sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)
renderer = sdl2.SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0)
texture = sdl2.SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, sdl2.SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888, sdl2.SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, 256, 256)
```

I tried the following:

```py
pic_as_string = "".join(map(chr, pic))
pointer = cast(c_char_p(pic_as_string), c_void_p)

sdl2.SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, None, pointer, 3*256)
```

Im currently using `pypy3`, if that's relevant.

Comment: A side note. `pygame` is a wrapper around `SDL` which is much easier for new folk in game dev.

Comment: Something like `pointer = cast(c_char_p(bytes(pic)), c_void_p)`? Also you told SDL your texture is static but you're trying to do opposite of static.

Answer (score 1):

It's preferable to store the framebuffer in a bytearray() instead of integers in a list, because then it's automatically a writeable array of bytes. You read/modify it the same way as a list (i.e. pic[0] = 255).

```
pic = bytearray([0xff]*256*256*3)
```

You can then create a ctypes char array using the same buffer:

```
pointer = (c_char*len(pic)).from_buffer(pic)
sdl2.SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, None, pointer, 3*256)
```

Also, you may want to use sdl2.SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING when creating the texture (indicating to SDL you intend on updating it).